# Issue with adding "import <RestKit/RestKit.h>" into AppDelegate.m

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, restkit

I am working with slightly older version of RestKit (downloaded it in September) and have put it into a new project.  I copied the RestKit project and all associated files into my project, then went to Build Settings on my project target and set "Other Linker Flags" to "-ObjC" and “Header Search Paths” to “$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../Headers”, including quotes.  I then went to "Build Phases" and added RestKit to Target Dependencies and CFNetwork, CoreData, libxml2, MobileCoreServices, QuartzCore, Security, and SystemConfiguration to the "Link Binary with Libraries" section.  Finally, the instructions state to add the following to the AppDelegate.m file:

```
import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
```

However, when I do that and build the project, I get an error stating that "'RestKit/RestKit.h' file not found."  I've followed these instructions before without an issue, but now it won't find the file.  What can I do to make sure it is seeing the RestKit files.  The instructions I am following are in this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial

Comment: Are you sure that path you constructed for searching is correct?  Why is it doubling back twice?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean.  I just followed along with the tutorial.  It has worked before, I'm just not sure why it isn't working now.

Answer (score 0):

The instruction of the following webpage should solve your problem:
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Tips-for-Troubleshooting-Your-Application

Comment: Which part of that should help me?  I didn't see anything that refers to this situation.

Comment: Upps sorry: i'd copy the wrong url. This is the right one: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installation-Troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it should work, but I tried a number of the settings in the build location window, and nothing seems to work.